# How can I change the .load method into direct usage of a variable from the html file in jQuery, for the schedule-template of CodyHouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the schedule-template(https://github.com/CodyHouse/schedule-template) to create a schedule. During this process we run into one error, when clicking on a specific activity in the schedule op pop-up window containing information about the event should appear, but the information text is missing. Reason for this is a CORS error, as the information is loaded from a file (line 119):

```
this.modalBody.find('.event-info').load(event.parent().attr('data-content')+'.html .event-info > *', function(data){
            //once the event content has been loaded
            self.element.addClass('content-loaded');
    });
```

An example of the content of a file that is loaded is something like this:

```
<div class="event-info">
<div>Abs Circuit. </div>
</div>
```

As loading data from a file results in a CORS error in chrome, it works properly in firefox, and a decent amount of other people should be able to access this schedule, my thoughts where to edit the line that loads the data from a file and instead directly load a string value from the html file. The data-content that is now loaded from the html file can be found in the lines like 69 of the provided html file.

```
<li class="single-event" data-start="09:30" data-end="10:30" data-content="event-abs-circuit" data-event="event-1">
```

This data-content is now extracted and used as the basis for the file-name of the file that is loaded, but in my opinion it would be way more useful in our case to just modify the data-content variable and directly use this data for the event-info. This would mean editing the

```
this.modalBody.find('.event-info').load(event.parent().attr('data-content')+'.html .event-info > *', function(data){
            //once the event content has been loaded
            self.element.addClass('content-loaded');
    });
```

to a line that changes the `.load` to simply an `event.parent().attr('data-content')` to get the data-content string and then input this into the `self.element.addClass(data-content string)`, so that that the event-info is loaded without using a file. As I am someone who has only programmed in python, I took a few stabs at the problem and tried several ways to change the code but mostly broke more than that I fixed.

All in all, I am of the opinion that through changing the earlier shown code fragment, we should be able to directly use the data from the data-content `<li class="single-event" data-start="09:30" data-end="10:30" data-content="event-abs-circuit" data-event="event-1">` to get the "event-abs-circuit" info, but I am stumped on how to do this. The original html file and js script have also been added to the question, in case I might be completely wrong in my assumption the solution should be in those lines.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var transitionEnd = 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend';
    var transitionsSupported = ( $('.csstransitions').length > 0 );
    //if browser does not support transitions - use a different event to trigger them
    if( !transitionsSupported ) transitionEnd = 'noTransition';
    
    //should add a loading while the events are organized 

    function SchedulePlan( element ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.timeline = this.element.find('.timeline');
        this.timelineItems = this.timeline.find('li');
        this.timelineItemsNumber = this.timelineItems.length;
        this.timelineStart = getScheduleTimestamp(this.timelineItems.eq(0).text());
        //need to store delta (in our case half hour) timestamp
        this.timelineUnitDuration = getScheduleTimestamp(this.timelineItems.eq(1).text()) - getScheduleTimestamp(this.timelineItems.eq(0).text());

        this.eventsWrapper = this.element.find('.events');
        this.eventsGroup = this.eventsWrapper.find('.events-group');
        this.singleEvents = this.eventsGroup.find('.single-event');
        this.eventSlotHeight = this.eventsGroup.eq(0).children('.top-info').outerHeight();

        this.modal = this.element.find('.event-modal');
        this.modalHeader = this.modal.find('.header');
        this.modalHeaderBg = this.modal.find('.header-bg');
        this.modalBody = this.modal.find('.body'); 
        this.modalBodyBg = this.modal.find('.body-bg'); 
        this.modalMaxWidth = 800;
        this.modalMaxHeight = 480;

        this.animating = false;

        this.initSchedule();
    }

    SchedulePlan.prototype.initSchedule = function() {
        this.scheduleReset();
        this.initEvents();
    };

    SchedulePlan.prototype.scheduleReset = function() {
        var mq = this.mq();
        if( mq == 'desktop' && !this.element.hasClass('js-full') ) {
            //in this case you are on a desktop version (first load or resize from mobile)
            this.eventSlotHeight = this.eventsGroup.eq(0).children('.top-info').outerHeight();
            this.element.addClass('js-full');
            this.placeEvents();
            this.element.hasClass('modal-is-open') && this.checkEventModal();
        } else if(  mq == 'mobile' && this.element.hasClass('js-full') ) {
            //in this case you are on a mobile version (first load or resize from desktop)
            this.element.removeClass('js-full loading');
            this.eventsGroup.children('ul').add(this.singleEvents).removeAttr('style');
            this.eventsWrapper.children('.grid-line').remove();
            this.element.hasClass('modal-is-open') && this.checkEventModal();
        } else if( mq == 'desktop' && this.element.hasClass('modal-is-open')){
            //on a mobile version with modal open - need to resize/move modal window
            this.checkEventModal('desktop');
            this.element.removeClass('loading');
        } else {
            this.element.removeClass('loading');
        }
    };

    SchedulePlan.prototype.initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        this.singleEvents.each(function(){
            //create the .event-date element for each event
            var durationLabel = '<span class="event-date">'+$(this).data('start')+' - '+$(this).data('end')+'</span>';
            $(this).children('a').prepend($(durationLabel));

            //detect click on the event and open the modal
            $(this).on('click', 'a', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                if( !self.animating ) self.openModal($(this));
            });
        });

        //close modal window
        this.modal.on('click', '.close', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if( !self.animating ) self.closeModal(self.eventsGroup.find('.selected-event'));
        });
        this.element.on('click', '.cover-layer', function(event){
            if( !self.animating && self.element.hasClass('modal-is-open') ) self.closeModal(self.eventsGroup.find('.selected-event'));
        });
    };

    SchedulePlan.prototype.placeEvents = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.singleEvents.each(function(){
            //place each event in the grid -> need to set top position and height
            var start = getScheduleTimestamp($(this).attr('data-start')),
                duration = getScheduleTimestamp($(this).attr('data-end')) - start;

            var eventTop = self.eventSlotHeight*(start - self.timelineStart)/self.timelineUnitDuration,
                eventHeight = self.eventSlotHeight*duration/self.timelineUnitDuration;
            
            $(this).css({
                top: (eventTop -1) +'px',
                height: (eventHeight+1)+'px'
            });
        });

        this.element.removeClass('loading');
    };

    SchedulePlan.prototype.openModal = function(event) {
        var self = this;
        var mq = self.mq();
        this.animating = true;

        //update event name and time
        this.modalHeader.find('.event-name').text(event.find('.event-name').text());
        this.modalHeader.find('.event-date').text(event.find('.event-date').text());
        this.modal.attr('data-event', event.parent().attr('data-event'));

        //update event content
        this.modalBody.find('.event-info').load(event.parent().attr('data-content')+'.html .event-info > *', function(data){
            //once the event content has been loaded
            self.element.addClass('content-loaded');
        });

        this.element.addClass('modal-is-open');

        setTimeout(function(){
            //fixes a flash when an event is selected - desktop version only
            event.parent('li').addClass('selected-event');
        }, 10);

        if( mq == 'mobile' ) {
            self.modal.one(transitionEnd, function(){
                self.modal.off(transitionEnd);
                self.animating = false;
            });
        } else {
            var eventTop = event.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
                eventLeft = event.offset().left,
                eventHeight = event.innerHeight(),
                eventWidth = event.innerWidth();

            var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height();

            var modalWidth = ( windowWidth*.8 > self.modalMaxWidth ) ? self.modalMaxWidth : windowWidth*.8,
                modalHeight = ( windowHeight*.8 > self.modalMaxHeight ) ? self.modalMaxHeight : windowHeight*.8;

            var modalTranslateX = parseInt((windowWidth - modalWidth)/2 - eventLeft),
                modalTranslateY = parseInt((windowHeight - modalHeight)/2 - eventTop);
            
            var HeaderBgScaleY = modalHeight/eventHeight,
                BodyBgScaleX = (modalWidth - eventWidth);

            //change modal height/width and translate it
            self.modal.css({
                top: eventTop+'px',
                left: eventLeft+'px',
                height: modalHeight+'px',
                width: modalWidth+'px',
            });
            transformElement(self.modal, 'translateY('+modalTranslateY+'px) translateX('+modalTranslateX+'px)');

            //set modalHeader width
            self.modalHeader.css({
                width: eventWidth+'px',
            });
            //set modalBody left margin
            self.modalBody.css({
                marginLeft: eventWidth+'px',
            });

            //change modalBodyBg height/width ans scale it
            self.modalBodyBg.css({
                height: eventHeight+'px',
                width: '1px',
            });
            transformElement(self.modalBodyBg, 'scaleY('+HeaderBgScaleY+') scaleX('+BodyBgScaleX+')');

            //change modal modalHeaderBg height/width and scale it
            self.modalHeaderBg.css({
                height: eventHeight+'px',
                width: eventWidth+'px',
            });
            transformElement(self.modalHeaderBg, 'scaleY('+HeaderBgScaleY+')');
            
            self.modalHeaderBg.one(transitionEnd, function(){
                //wait for the  end of the modalHeaderBg transformation and show the modal content
                self.modalHeaderBg.off(transitionEnd);
                self.animating = false;
                self.element.addClass('animation-completed');
            });
        }

        //if browser do not support transitions -> no need to wait for the end of it
        if( !transitionsSupported ) self.modal.add(self.modalHeaderBg).trigger(transitionEnd);
    };

    SchedulePlan.prototype.closeModal = function(event) {
        var self = this;
        var mq = self.mq();

        this.animating = true;

        if( mq == 'mobile' ) {
            this.element.removeClass('modal-is-open');
            this.modal.one(transitionEnd, function(){
                self.modal.off(transitionEnd);
                self.animating = false;
                self.element.removeClass('content-loaded');
                event.removeClass('selected-event');
            });
        } else {
            var eventTop = event.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
                eventLeft = event.offset().left,
                eventHeight = event.innerHeight(),
                eventWidth = event.innerWidth();

            var modalTop = Number(self.modal.css('top').replace('px', '')),
                modalLeft = Number(self.modal.css('left').replace('px', ''));

            var modalTranslateX = eventLeft - modalLeft,
                modalTranslateY = eventTop - modalTop;

            self.element.removeClass('animation-completed modal-is-open');

            //change modal width/height and translate it
            this.modal.css({
                width: eventWidth+'px',
                height: eventHeight+'px'
            });
            transformElement(self.modal, 'translateX('+modalTranslateX+'px) translateY('+modalTranslateY+'px)');
            
            //scale down modalBodyBg element
            transformElement(self.modalBodyBg, 'scaleX(0) scaleY(1)');
            //scale down modalHeaderBg element
            transformElement(self.modalHeaderBg, 'scaleY(1)');

            this.modalHeaderBg.one(transitionEnd, function(){
                //wait for the  end of the modalHeaderBg transformation and reset modal style
                self.modalHeaderBg.off(transitionEnd);
                self.modal.addClass('no-transition');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    self.modal.add(self.modalHeader).add(self.modalBody).add(self.modalHeaderBg).add(self.modalBodyBg).attr('style', '');
                }, 10);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    self.modal.removeClass('no-transition');
                }, 20);

                self.animating = false;
                self.element.removeClass('content-loaded');
                event.removeClass('selected-event');
            });
        }

        //browser do not support transitions -> no need to wait for the end of it
        if( !transitionsSupported ) self.modal.add(self.modalHeaderBg).trigger(transitionEnd);
    }

    SchedulePlan.prototype.mq = function(){
        //get MQ value ('desktop' or 'mobile') 
        var self = this;
        return window.getComputedStyle(this.element.get(0), '::before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/["']/g, '');
    };

    SchedulePlan.prototype.checkEventModal = function(device) {
        this.animating = true;
        var self = this;
        var mq = this.mq();

        if( mq == 'mobile' ) {
            //reset modal style on mobile
            self.modal.add(self.modalHeader).add(self.modalHeaderBg).add(self.modalBody).add(self.modalBodyBg).attr('style', '');
            self.modal.removeClass('no-transition');    
            self.animating = false; 
        } else if( mq == 'desktop' && self.element.hasClass('modal-is-open') ) {
            self.modal.addClass('no-transition');
            self.element.addClass('animation-completed');
            var event = self.eventsGroup.find('.selected-event');

            var eventTop = event.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
                eventLeft = event.offset().left,
                eventHeight = event.innerHeight(),
                eventWidth = event.innerWidth();

            var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height();

            var modalWidth = ( windowWidth*.8 > self.modalMaxWidth ) ? self.modalMaxWidth : windowWidth*.8,
                modalHeight = ( windowHeight*.8 > self.modalMaxHeight ) ? self.modalMaxHeight : windowHeight*.8;

            var HeaderBgScaleY = modalHeight/eventHeight,
                BodyBgScaleX = (modalWidth - eventWidth);

            setTimeout(function(){
                self.modal.css({
                    width: modalWidth+'px',
                    height: modalHeight+'px',
                    top: (windowHeight/2 - modalHeight/2)+'px',
                    left: (windowWidth/2 - modalWidth/2)+'px',
                });
                transformElement(self.modal, 'translateY(0) translateX(0)');
                //change modal modalBodyBg height/width
                self.modalBodyBg.css({
                    height: modalHeight+'px',
                    width: '1px',
                });
                transformElement(self.modalBodyBg, 'scaleX('+BodyBgScaleX+')');
                //set modalHeader width
                self.modalHeader.css({
                    width: eventWidth+'px',
                });
                //set modalBody left margin
                self.modalBody.css({
                    marginLeft: eventWidth+'px',
                });
                //change modal modalHeaderBg height/width and scale it
                self.modalHeaderBg.css({
                    height: eventHeight+'px',
                    width: eventWidth+'px',
                });
                transformElement(self.modalHeaderBg, 'scaleY('+HeaderBgScaleY+')');
            }, 10);

            setTimeout(function(){
                self.modal.removeClass('no-transition');
                self.animating = false; 
            }, 20);
        }
    };

    var schedules = $('.cd-schedule');
    var objSchedulesPlan = [],
        windowResize = false;
    
    if( schedules.length > 0 ) {
        schedules.each(function(){
            //create SchedulePlan objects
            objSchedulesPlan.push(new SchedulePlan($(this)));
        });
    }

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if( !windowResize ) {
            windowResize = true;
            (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? setTimeout(checkResize) : window.requestAnimationFrame(checkResize);
        }
    });

    $(window).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            objSchedulesPlan.forEach(function(element){
                element.closeModal(element.eventsGroup.find('.selected-event'));
            });
        }
    });

    function checkResize(){
        objSchedulesPlan.forEach(function(element){
            element.scheduleReset();
        });
        windowResize = false;
    }

    function getScheduleTimestamp(time) {
        //accepts hh:mm format - convert hh:mm to timestamp
        time = time.replace(/ /g,'');
        var timeArray = time.split(':');
        var timeStamp = parseInt(timeArray[0])*60 + parseInt(timeArray[1]);
        return timeStamp;
    }

    function transformElement(element, value) {
        element.css({
            '-moz-transform': value,
            '-webkit-transform': value,
            '-ms-transform': value,
            '-o-transform': value,
            'transform': value
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    
    <title>Schedule Template | CodyHouse</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cd-schedule loading">
    <div class="timeline">
        <ul>
            <li><span>09:00</span></li>
            <li><span>09:30</span></li>
            <li><span>10:00</span></li>
            <li><span>10:30</span></li>
            <li><span>11:00</span></li>
            <li><span>11:30</span></li>
            <li><span>12:00</span></li>
            <li><span>12:30</span></li>
            <li><span>13:00</span></li>
            <li><span>13:30</span></li>
            <li><span>14:00</span></li>
            <li><span>14:30</span></li>
            <li><span>15:00</span></li>
            <li><span>15:30</span></li>
            <li><span>16:00</span></li>
            <li><span>16:30</span></li>
            <li><span>17:00</span></li>
            <li><span>17:30</span></li>
            <li><span>18:00</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- .timeline -->

    <div class="events">
        <ul>
            <li class="events-group">
                <div class="top-info"><span>Monday</span></div>

                <ul>
                    <li class="single-event" data-start="09:30" data-end="10:30" data-content="event-abs-circuit" data-event="event-1">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Abs Circuit</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="11:00" data-end="12:30" data-content="event-rowing-workout" data-event="event-2">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Rowing Workout</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="14:00" data-end="15:15"  data-content="event-yoga-1" data-event="event-3">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Yoga Level 1</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="events-group">
                <div class="top-info"><span>Tuesday</span></div>

                <ul>
                    <li class="single-event" data-start="10:00" data-end="11:00"  data-content="event-rowing-workout" data-event="event-2">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Rowing Workout</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="11:30" data-end="13:00"  data-content="event-restorative-yoga" data-event="event-4">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Restorative Yoga</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="13:30" data-end="15:00" data-content="event-abs-circuit" data-event="event-1">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Abs Circuit</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="15:45" data-end="16:45"  data-content="event-yoga-1" data-event="event-3">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Yoga Level 1</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="events-group">
                <div class="top-info"><span>Wednesday</span></div>

                <ul>
                    <li class="single-event" data-start="09:00" data-end="10:15" data-content="event-restorative-yoga" data-event="event-4">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Restorative Yoga</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="10:45" data-end="11:45" data-content="event-yoga-1" data-event="event-3">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Yoga Level 1</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="12:00" data-end="13:45"  data-content="event-rowing-workout" data-event="event-2">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Rowing Workout</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="13:45" data-end="15:00" data-content="event-yoga-1" data-event="event-3">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Yoga Level 1</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="events-group">
                <div class="top-info"><span>Thursday</span></div>

                <ul>
                    <li class="single-event" data-start="09:30" data-end="10:30" data-content="event-abs-circuit" data-event="event-1">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Abs Circuit</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="12:00" data-end="13:45" data-content="event-restorative-yoga" data-event="event-4">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Restorative Yoga</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="15:30" data-end="16:30" data-content="event-abs-circuit" data-event="event-1">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Abs Circuit</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="17:00" data-end="18:30"  data-content="event-rowing-workout" data-event="event-2">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Rowing Workout</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="events-group">
                <div class="top-info"><span>Friday</span></div>

                <ul>
                    <li class="single-event" data-start="10:00" data-end="11:00"  data-content="event-rowing-workout" data-event="event-2">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Rowing Workout</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="12:30" data-end="14:00" data-content="event-abs-circuit" data-event="event-1">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Abs Circuit</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="single-event" data-start="15:45" data-end="16:45"  data-content="event-yoga-1" data-event="event-3">
                        <a href="#0">
                            <em class="event-name">Yoga Level 1</em>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="event-modal">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="content">
                <span class="event-date"></span>
                <h3 class="event-name"></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="header-bg"></div>
        </header>

        <div class="body">
            <div class="event-info"></div>
            <div class="body-bg"></div>
        </div>

        <a href="#0" class="close">Close</a>
    </div>

    <div class="cover-layer"></div>
</div> <!-- .cd-schedule -->
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if( !window.jQuery ) document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```